# Hold the value of first column (i.e id )and match with all value of onother column (i.e parent_id) in same table php

Tags: cakephp

I am working in a cakephp project. Actually i have table `menu_items` in database, which contains `id`, `parent_id`, `title`, `url` and `is_active`. My Parent menu items are displaying properly but the problem is in sub menu which are related to `parent_id`.

```
foreach($menusitems as $menu) 
{
     if($menu['MenuItem']['is_active'] == true)
     {
          echo $this->Html->link($menu['MenuItem']['title'], array('controller' => 'pages', action' => $menu['MenuItem']['url']));

         foreach ($menu['MenuItem'] as $temp) 
         {
            if($id == $temp['parent_id'])
            {
                echo "match";
            }
        }

     }  

}
```

It is not a proper code, I just want to match particular id(ex: 1) want to match with every value of parent id in first go so where I will find the matching value I will print that value's title in a sub menu list and the same process with next id (ex: 2) and so on. But my matching id with parent id is not working.

```
 When i use

'echo "<pre>"
 print_r($menus);
 echo "</pre>"
'
'Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [parent_id] => 
    [title] => Home
    [url] => home
    [is_active] => 1
)

 Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [parent_id] => 
    [title] => Profile
    [url] => 
    [is_active] => 1
)

 Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [parent_id] => 
    [title] => Home
    [url] => home
    [is_active] => 1
)

Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [parent_id] => 2
    [title] => Bussiness Profile
    [url] => bussiness_profile
    [is_active] => 1
)'
```

I just want to show bussiness as a sub menu under Profile. I am matching if id i.e 1 is equals to any parent id. If any parent id exists like "Bussiness Profile" in my casethen thats item should display as a sub menu of Profile.

Comment: what does "It is not a proper code" mean? Sounds like you want to use [find('threaded')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded) - hard to tell though.

Comment: i edited some code i hope that would sufficient to you.

Answer (score 0):

`find ('threaded')` does the trick for you. 
Use `$this->MenuItem->find('threaded', array('conditions' => array('MenuItem.is_active')))` in your Controller, should return you an array looking like

```
[0] => array(
    ['MenuItem'] => array(
        [id] => 1
        [parent_id] => 
        [title] => Home
        [url] => home
        [is_active] => 1
     ),
),
[1] => array(
    ['MenuItem'] => array(
        [id] => 2
        [parent_id] => 
        [title] => Profile
        [url] => home
        [is_active] => 1
     ),
     ['children'] => array(
          [MenuItem] => array(
               [id] => 4
               [parent_id] => 2
               [title] => Bussiness Profile
               [url] => bussiness_profile
               [is_active] => 1
          )
     )
 .
 .
)
```

so, in your view:

```
<ul class="menu">
<?php foreach($menuitems as $menu_item_parent): ?>
     <li class="parent">
         //$this->Html->link .. (with $menu_item_parent)

         <?php if(!empty($menu_item_parent['children'])): ?>
              <ul class="submenu">
              <?php foreach($menuitems['children'] as $menu_item_child): ?>
                    <li class="child">
                          //$this->Html->link .. (with $menu_item_child)
                    </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              </ul>
         <?php endif; ?>
     </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```